# Creating a Metadata Record with a lookup field

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I am working with custom metadata types and I have created a lookup field to another Custom MDT. I need to create the records with Apex, and as of I now I can successfully create the records the only thing is I cant fill the lookup field value even if I use the Id of the record I want to look up to.

```
sObject baseTheme = [SELECT MasterLabel, Font_Color__c FROM Workboard_Theme__mdt WHERE MasterLabel = 'Summer'];
            Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
            String nameSpacePrefix = ''; // if the metadata belongs to any package unclude the namespace

            Metadata.CustomMetadata MDTRecord = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
            MDTRecord.fullName = nameSpacePrefix + 'Workboard_Setting__mdt.FirstRec';
            MDTRecord.label = 'TestRec';

            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue userIdField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            userIdField.field = 'UserId__c';
            userIdField.value = 'A213Test';
    
            MDTRecord.values.add(userIdField);
    
            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue themeLookup = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            themeLookup.field = 'Workboard_Theme__c';
            themeLookup.value = 'm012g0000004N67AAE';
    
            MDTRecord.values.add(themeLookup);
    
            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue ListViewField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            ListViewField.field = 'CurrentListViewId__c';
            ListViewField.value = ' 00B2g000001MYIEEA4';
            
            MDTRecord.values.add(ListViewField);

            mdContainer.addMetadata(MDTRecord);

            CustomMetadataCallback callback = new CustomMetadataCallback();

            Id jobid = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);

            System.debug('jobId *** ' + jobid);
```

[image: The Metatata object structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like a regular MD API deploy, you'll use the name, not the ID, of the target of your lookup. So instead of m012g0000004N67A, you'd use something like "MyOtherMetadataType__mdt.MyOtherRecord".